# How to parse JS values to JSP page

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have provided confirm box via JS for delete but even user click on cancel my delete query execute, i want user to remain on same page if he click on cancel.
jsp code -:

```
<td><a href="deletehyper?value=<%= id2  %>"><img src="delete.png" height="18" width="18" onclick="myFunction()"></a></td>
```

parsing js variable in jsp -:

```
<%

 String name=(String)request.getParameter("r");
 System.out.println(name);
%>
```

JS code -:

```
function myFunction(){    
  var r=alert("You are about to delete ");
  if(r == true){    
    return true;
  }else{    
    return false;
  }
}
```

please suggest me

Comment: By `alert`, did you mean to use `confirm`? I don't think alert prompts. Also, you could just `return` the value directly, no need for the `if` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

For your HTML (note the addition of the return and moving the `onclick` into the `a`):

```
<a href="deletehyper?value=<%= id2  %>" onclick="return myFunction()"><img src="delete.png" height="18" width="18"></a>
```

For your JavaScript (correct function, simplified):

```
function myFunction()
{
  return confirm("You are about to delete ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`alert` doesn't return anything, you need `confirm`.

I think your `<img>` onclick event should be on your `<a>` element instead, since it's the link you want to cancel.

...and when doing event handlers inline, you need to `onclick="return myFunction()"` to return the true or false from myFunction to the inline onclick handler, cancelling the link and staying on the page.

And instead of `if(r = true) return true else return false;` you can just `return r`.

Your JSP will not receive 'r', `r` will not be a request parameter unless you append it to the `href` value of the link as a URL parameter.  Since your confirmation is performed client-side in JavaScript, and the link is cancelled client-side in JavaScript, you won't be able to detect this server-side in your JSP.

Comment: Oh, lol, what Evan said...  Except the event is best on the `<a>` element, not the `<img>` element.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after and tweaked.